# Почему надо говорить квартАл?

Tags: орфоэпия

На какой слог падает ударение в слове квартал? Ответ однозначный: ударение падает на второй слог - кварт**а**л (во всех значениях). Но тогда почему  можно услышать это слово с ударным первым слогом, хотя считается, что такого произношения никогда в русском языке не существовало, и ни одним словарем оно не зафиксировано.

А история у этого слова не совсем простая. В значении "четвертая часть года" слово заимствовано в Петровскую эпоху из немецкого языка, но восходит оно к латыни. В значении "городской квартал" слово заимствовано уже непосредственно из немецкого языка в конце XVIII в. (от Viertel).

И вопросы.

1) На какой слог падает ударение в немецком и латинском словах?

2) Каково происхождение "неправильного " ударения в русском варианте?

3) Как оно вошло в профессиональный язык бухгалтеров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Квартал" в обоих значениях происходит от немецкого слова латинского происхождения. Немецкое "Qurtal" имеет ударение на последний слог, откуда оно и в русском. В латинском слове "quartale" (четверть) ударение также ставится на вторую "а". В сленге же бухгалтеров  вероятнее всего ударение сместилось под влиянием слова "кварта".

Comment: Кварта в музыке (от лат. quarta - четверть, четвертая часть) — интервал шириной в четыре ступени. Бухгалтеры так музыкальны? Появились они в России уже в начале 18 века (как книговоды) судя по таким записям: "сыскат бухгалтаря". И вот с этого времени они неправильно ставят ударение?

Comment: Бухгалтеры появились на Руси как минимум с XI века, но назывались в те времена "ключники". Когда стали произносить "квАртал" доподлинно установить вряд ли возможно, но это соответствует тенденции переноса ударения в двусложных словах с конца слова в начало (см. токарь, паспорт, случай и пр.)

Comment: Тогда получается, что бухгалтеры на верном пути и мы можем считать их нашим языковым авангардом.

Comment: @София Неизвестно, музыкальны ли бухгалтеры, но выпить точно любят - кварта это не только музыкальный интервал, но и две пинты пива!

Answer (score 0):

Все орфографические словари, за исключением словаря Кузнецова, говорят о том, что ударение делается на второй слог. Словарь Кузнецова допускает ударение на первом слоге, но только при использовании слова профессионалами. Ударение на первый слог допустимо только в профессиональном жаргоне, и то не стоит этим злоупотреблять. (http://pro-udarenie.ru/udarenie-v-slove-kvartal.html#primer-1)

Answer (score -1):

У этого слова два существенно различающихся значения: временной — это четверть года и отчетный период у плательщиков налогов, а значит и бухгалтеров, и планировочный — часть городского массива, ограниченного улицами.

Так вот, в первом случае ударение действительно ставится на последний слог — кварт**а**л, а вот во втором случае, следует произносить с ударением на первый слог — кв**а**ртал. Почему? Да потому, что следует эти понятия различать. Мы не англосаксы, у которых одно и тоже слово, подразумевает несколько разных значений.

Comment: Как же мы живём и отличаем косу от косы, а ту в свою очередь от косы?...